# Using the value of an object as the name of another object

Tags: jquery, local-storage

First, I want to apologize for the ambiguous title :)
Second, I'm a novice with jQuery.

I have a drop down with two values ("taget1" and "target2"). On page load, I'm setting the localStorage with a URL for each target (target1=google.com and target2=gmail.com).

When the drop down changes, I set a "lastSelection" var in localStorage (lastSelection=target2).

Now, I also want to get the relevant URL from localStorage. So when I change to "target2" I want to get the saved URL from localStorage. Instead of using an "if", I thought I can use the val() of the drop down.

This did not work:

```
var url = localStorage.getItem([lastSelection])
```

How can I use the value of lastSelection to get a result like `localStorage.getItem('target2')`?

Comment: Well, you COULD use `eval(lastSelection)`, but that's a bad approach for a number of reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems 'target1' and 'target2' are text that appear in the dropdown. You could use:

```
var selectedText = $("#dropdownId option:selected").text();
```

If they refer to the actual value of the options instead of text, then

```
var selectedValue = $("#dropdownId option:selected").val();
```

Now you can use selectedText or selectedValue, which ever one you want as a parameter to get stuff from local storage.

```
var url = localStorage.getItem(selectedText);
```

Answer (score 0):

`val()` will give you the selected value of the dropdown. Try this

```
localStorage.getItem($("dropdownSelector").val());
```

So if you select `target1` in the `dropdown` it will give you `google.com` and for `target2` it will give you `gmail.com` as expected.